# Send uncaught exception to google analytic

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm trying to send uncaught exception to google analytic for two weeks and I cannot find a full example that explain how I can do that, I found many examples but they are not complete and did not work for me, even google-developer is not clear and did not explain it from A to Z.
Do someone know any resource that explain how to do that step by step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to integrate Google Analytics and to only send unhanded exceptions for Android is:

1. Integrate latest Google Play Services with your app. [Link to instructions here](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html). Don't forget to add the play service version meta element to your AndroidManifest.xml, its is required for correct function of Analytics:

   ```
   <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
   ```
2. Create app class that extends [android.app.Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) and override [onCreate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate()) method. See the [minimal Google Analytics Hello World app](https://github.com/googleanalytics/hello-world-android-app) on the Google Analytics github as example.
3. In your App on onCreate override initialize Google Analytics, create your default app tracker and enable exception reporting. You don't need xml configuration. It's simpler to just do that from code:

   ```
   private static GoogleAnalytics analytics;
   private static Tracker tracker;
   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
       analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
       tracker = analytics.newTracker("UA-00000-1"); // Replace with your tracker id
       tracker.enableExceptionReporting(true);
   }
   ```
4. Add the required (and optional) permissions to your manifest. Analytics needs network to send your hits. The optional wake lock permission help with reliable dispatching:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
   <!-- optional wake lock permission -->
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
   ```

   5.Register your app as the Application implementation by setting name attribute of the application element in AndroidManifest.xml to your app class:

   ```
   <application android:name=".YourAppClass" ... />
   ```
5. Register the recommended AnalyticsReceiver & AnalyticsService in your AndroidManifest.xml:

   ```
   <application>
       ...
       <!-- Enable background dispatching to improve delivery on non-Google Play devices -->
       <receiver
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
           android:enabled="true">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH"/>
           </intent-filter>
       </receiver>
       <service
           android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
           android:enabled="true"
           android:exported="false"/>
       ...
   </application>
   ```

Comment: Thank you but with what Google Analytic version this will work?

Comment: Latest - Google Play Service 7.3

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have Google Analytics set up for your project and you are using Google Analytics V4, all you need to do is add the following to your Google Analytics XML configuration file:

```
<bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
```

Source: [Crashes & Exceptions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/exceptions) documentation for the Google Analytics Android SDK.

Comment: I do not think you read my question, Im asking about the full stept ro send uncaught exception to GA..I read that source many times before and it's one of the sources I ever saw.

Comment: I'm not sure what is unclear about that. Do you have Google Analytics working *at all*, or are you really trying to ask how to integrate Google Analytics in general?

Comment: Yes I'm asking how to integrate google analytic step by step to send uncaught exception.

Comment: In that case, you haven't provided nearly enough information for us to help you. What configuration have you already done in your project? What results are you seeing in Google Analytics? I have found the [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/) to be more than sufficient in the past- where in that guide are you having issues?